# Import data and python scripts in azure ml entry script when deploying models

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, web-deployment, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an existing machine learning model saved on my local system. I want to deploy this model as a web service so I can consume this model as a request-response i.e. send an HTTP request to the model and get back a predicted response.

When attempting to deploy this model on AzureML I run into a few problems

The model needs to be initialized in an entry script int the init() function, but for initializing my model I have a custom class and require few txt files to be loaded.

below is the code to initialize the model object

```
from model_file import MyModelClass  # this is the file which contains the model class

def init():
  global robert_model

  my_model = MyModelClass(vocab_path='<path-to-text-files>',
                          model_paths=['<path-to-model-file>'],
                          iterations=5,
                          min_error_probability=0.0,
                          min_probability=0.0,
                          weigths=None)
def run(json_data):
  try:
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    preds, cnt = my_model.handle_batch([sentence.split()])
    return {'output': pred, 'count': cnt}
  except Exception as e:
    error = str(e)
    return error
```

I don't know how to import those class files and text files in the entry script

I don't know much about azure, and I am having a hard time figuring this out. Please help.

Answer (score 6):

**I found the solution:**

The solution was right there I just had to read more in the official documentation. Below I have explained the solution to my problem.

When deploying a model on Azure Machine Learning Studio we have to prepare 3 things:

1. *[Entry Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-existing-model#entry-script-scorepy)* is the actual python script that makes predictions.
2. *[Deployment Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-existing-model#define-deployment)* can be thought of as the computer where your model will run.
3. *[Inference Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py)* defines the software dependencies of your model. It is here, where we can also provide text/static files.

The `inferece_config` takes an argument called `source_directory`. We can provide a path to a folder to the *source_directory* argument like below

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    entry_script="<entry-script.py>",
    environment=myenv, 
    source_directory="<path-to-your-folder>",
)
```

We can place all our requirements in this folder, including text, static, CSV, python scripts, etc files. The *entry script* must also be placed in this folder.
This folder will be directly copied by azure in the deployment image that gets created. This way we can access these files in the *entry script* using regular python syntax.

***For my solution:***

If I have my `inference_config` like this

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    entry_script="score.py", 
    environment=myenv, 
    source_directory='./assets',
)
```

And have this in the `./assets` folder

```
assets
├── my_model_class.py
├── score.py
└── data
    └── vocaublary.txt

1 directory, 3 files
```

Then my entry script (*score.py*) will look something like this:

```
from assets.my_model_class import MyModelClass
    
def init():
  global my_model
  model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), 
                            'my_model.pkl',)

  my_model = MyModelClass(vocab_path='assets/data/vocaublary.txt', 
                          model_path=model_path,)

def run(json_data):
  try:
    data = json.loads(json_data)
    prediction = my_model.predict(data)
    return {'data': prediction}
  except Exception as e:
    // do error handling
    return error
```

**Note:** We have to import from `assets.my_model_class` even though `score.py` is present in `assets` folder because, after deployment the CWD(Current Working Directory) changes to be the parent folder of `assets` folder

Answer (score 1):

The additional files related to a model can be uploaded directly to Azure ML Workspace(*with GUI*) in source-directory, which is *HOME > Notebooks*. (Refer to the image).
[image: Azure workspace image]

Add files into this(source-directory) using, *Add Files button*

The uploaded files can be accessed *os.getEnv()* method.

```
from azureml.core import Workspace
from azureml.core import Environment
import os

# Connect to WS
ws = Workspace(subscription_id="sid",
               resource_group="rg",
               workspace_name="wsname")

# Creating inference Config for demo
env = Environment(name='environment_name')
inf_config = InferenceConfig(environment=env, source_directory=os.getenv('ENV_NAME'), entry_script='./score.py')
```

Comment: This looks good. I will surely try this whenever I get a chance. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For txt/static files - you could upload to Azure Blobs and consume them on fly.
And for classes, you can encapsulate your classes inside the modules.

There are 2 options you could do here

**Option 1 :**

You could publish your module to pip and then consume it.

**Option 2 :**

The "Private wheel files" solution as described in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments#private-wheel-files).
The below is the sample environment and pls look closely under the **pip** section.

```
name: project_environment
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.

  # Currently Azure ML only supports 3.5.2 and later.

- python=3.6.2

- pip:
  - scikit-learn==0.22.1
  - azureml-defaults
  - https://myworkspaceid.blob.core/azureml/Environment/azureml-private-packages/my-wheel-file-name.whl
channels:
- conda-forge
```

Saw a reference code and similar discussion in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59176241/import-custom-python-module-in-azure-ml-deployment-environment).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have found an easier method, while deploying the model we can specify a folder containing the static files and package files in the `inference_config`. This folder is copied while deployment and can be consumed in the entry script. Thanks for the help

Comment: Read more about `inference_config` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py)

Comment: Please consider posting your implementation / recommendation as an answer. It will help the community

Comment: Yes sure. I have added my solution as an answer to this question.