# How to import scripts to Azure ML when deploying model with v2?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64257530/import-data-and-python-scripts-in-azure-ml-entry-script-when-deploying-models) and refers to **Create Inference Resources** in [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-deploy-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2).

I've constructed a simple model based on Heart Disease dataset that has a simple tweak: it uses a pre-defined transformer that removes outliers (I called it OutlierRemover) so the model pipeline looks like this:

[image: Model Pipeline]

In case of v1 version I simply used store it in the /assets folder and used

```
inference_config = InferenceConfig(
entry_script="score.py", 
environment=myenv, 
source_directory='./assets')
```

And imported it to my score.py script.

However, the documentation related to the migration doesn't show an option to add it in v2. The equivalent function:

```
# configure an inference configuration with a scoring script
from azure.ai.ml.entities import CodeConfiguration
code_config = CodeConfiguration(
    code="../model-1/onlinescoring", scoring_script="score.py"
)
```

Does not seem to have an argument to store the additional files like, in my case, outlierremover.py

Is there any smooth way to deal with it?

EDIT:

there is an option to add custom scripts during the deployment:

[image]

But I can't see such option in the Python SDK v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to include additional files is by placing them in the same directory as your scoring script.

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-online-endpoints?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#define-the-deployment),

| Attribute | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Code path | The path to the directory on the local development environment that contains `all the Python source code` for scoring the model. You can use nested directories and packages. |

In your case, you can place the `outlierremover.py` file in the same directory as your `score.py` script.

For example, if your directory structure looks like this:

```
onlinescoring/
├── score.py
└── outlierremover.py
```

When the endpoint is deployed, `onlinescoring` directory will be uploaded.
[image]

Then, in your `score.py` script, you can import the `OutlierRemover` class or any other functions from the `outlierremover.py` file.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. However, while following the deployment tutorial I keep encountering errors when using the command you shared -> the Azure ML seems to be unable to locate my model when I run it from azure Notebooks

Comment: The command will also upload the model. So, please add model location as per [tutorial](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/endpoints/online/managed/online-endpoints-simple-deployment.ipynb).

Comment: That's exactly what I've been doing - I cloned the repo and tried to deploy it with Azure Notebooks. However, the ml_client.online_deployments.begin_create_or_update(
    deployment=blue_deployment, local=True
) crashes as the model can not be found.

Comment: It seems that the artifact crreated in your tuttorial is stored as a normal .pkl file and not in the model/pklfile.pkl and it causes an error. No idea what is wrong herre.

Comment: Your tutorial script has a typo in score.py -> in model_path "model/sklearn_regression_model.pkl" causes error. It works without 'model/' part.

Answer (score -1):

To import scripts to Azure Machine Learning (Azure ML) when deploying a model using the v2 API you can follow these steps:

1. Prepare Your Scripts
2. Create a Deployment Configuration
3. Package Your Scripts
4. Upload Scripts to Azure ML Workspace
5. Define Deployment Configuration
6. Create a Model Object
7. Deploy Your Model
8. Monitor Deployment

I hope this will help you to understand and clear your doubt.